# UK car insurance when switching from International driving license to full UK driving license

Tags: united-kingdom, driving-license, car-insurance

***UPDATE: I called my insurer. they took my UK full driving license details.  There is No extra fee charged! At least until February. We'll see what happens in February at the renewal.***

I've an international driving license i hold for more than 12 years.

I've been living in the UK since late Oct 2022. I bought a car in Feb 2023 and insured myself using my driving license from my home country. My driving license is valid for 1 year until late Oct 2023.

Last month I took the driving test and passed. And received my Full UK driving license. I know I have to notify my insurance company.

When i let my insurer know that i got a my UK full driving license, i guess my insurer will draft a new policy with a new premium. Is it correct?

Do you think my premium will skyrocket? because i am suspecting that they will see me as a new driver since my UK license is really new. and ignore my 12 years old international driving license.

The reason of this suspicion is the following: i go to comparethemarket where i bought my insurance when i got the car. Get a new quote with entering my new UK driving license and i can see that the cheapest offer is more than double of what i paid in February.

Well, I haven't spoken with the insurer as of now, because i can still use my foreign licence and I don't want to create a problem that still doesn't exist.

Comment: Did they actually ask how old your British driving license is, or how old your driving license is? Of course with a two month old license you will pay a huge amount. But if you have been driving for ten years it _should_ make you count as an experienced driver.

Comment: I am in a similar situation. Wonder if you managed to find a way around it?

Comment: @gnasher729 sorry for late response. When i called my insurer to let them know that i got my UK Full license, they asked the date of issue of new license

Comment: @Marlboro sorry for late response. As i write in the original post as an update, I called my insurer. they took my UK full driving license details. There was no extra fee charged!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find insurers that take your previous non-UK driving record into account. For example [Marshmallow](https://www.marshmallow.com/insurance-for-expats?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=16698616531&utm_term=kwd-313851999241&gclid=CjwKCAjwg4SpBhAKEiwAdyLwvJEOYee9kcd5dvEn_HJM32o8w5gvHxrOlGf-uwmxK4AeCpRQczMo9RoCCk4QAvD_BwE)

Comment: Just their rules may be different. In Germany, you might have a 10 year "no accident" discount, and if you have an accident today it goes down to a 7 year discount, while in the UK you would have no discount. So if they ask "how many years without accidents" in the UK, that is meant literally, and a Germany insurance company might just not get what they are asking for.